# User Authenticaiton with xml. C#

Tags: c#, xml, authentication

I am trying to loop though it with this code but I only get the first username and password correct any other one is incorrect. Which means it’s only looping thought one user.

```
            XmlDocument mac = new XmlDocument();
            mac.Load(@"C:\Users\user\source\repos\lilis shop\lilis shop\Properties\XMLFile1.xml");
            XmlNodeList xnlist = mac.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//logins//users");

            foreach (XmlNode naa in xnlist)
            {
                string username = naa["/username"].InnerText;
                string password = naa["/password"].InnerText;

                if (username == txtusername.Text && password == txtpassword.Text)
                {
                    Letsee = "LOGEDIN";
                    Form1 openform = new Form1();
                    openform.lablogin.Text = Letsee;
                    openform.lab1.Text = this.txtusername.Text;
                    openform.labelsingout.Text = "SINGOUT";

                    openform.Show();

                    this.Hide();
                    break;

                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please enter the correct password or username", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtpassword.Text = null;
                    txtusername.Text = null;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: cant you use a breakpoint to see whats happening during the 2nd loop? Also would be helpful to see the xml

Answer (score -1):

This may be problem of blank space.
You have to debug this foreach loop to check exact value.